# Sigma value for defect ratio

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

What is the smallest sigma value (out of $1\sigma$, $2\sigma$, $3\sigma$, $4\sigma$, $5\sigma$, $6\sigma$) we can use when we want a less than 0.3% defect ratio?

My idea is to use $68-95-99.7$ rule, and obtain $3\sigma$ as an answer. Is it correct approach, or has missing parts?

Comment: So, is the answer equal to $3\sigma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to ask you here (since I can't comment yet) why would you choose $6σ$.

Since 99.7% means less than 0.3% defect ratio, maybe if we take an additional $σ$ only we would be in a safe place, in my opinion. Therefore, my answer would be $4σ$ (***3 is already safe for your question***).

***New Information***

As I mentioned, since we are talking about defects, it's more about the Six Sigma and the Sigma Level. Therefore, if we go to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma) page, we can see that the value should be between 4 and 5 Sigma Levels.

Now, we go back to our original SIGMAs,  which are easier to understand.
Our goal is to get 0.3% defect, or 99.7% good.
Therefore, we take our table of values we know that within 3σ we get 0.9973. Therefore, the real value should be a bit less than $3σ$. But we can go with $3σ$

***Being Very Precise***

[Table for Z-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) if you read the table you will find 2.75 Sigma for 0.99702.

**Reference**

[Quora Difference between Sigma and Sigma Level](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-difference-between-the-standard-deviation-and-the-sigma-level-If-yes-how-are-they-both-calculated-What-is-the-relation-between-them)

Comment: I used the rule mentioned in the problem statement. Is there any solid reason choosing $4\sigma$?

Comment: Is there any idea for solving this problem?

Comment: @rasul_rza24 I will give you the answer in a bit. I am doing my research to provide you with a good answer that will cover all your doubts.

Comment: @rasul_rza24 What you are looking for is Sigma metric. Since you are looking for 0.3% defect ratio, that means you require 0.003 equivalent of 3000 defects per 1'000'000 produced pieces. Therefore, you are looking for this number. You can calculate it here https://www.westgard.com/six-sigma-calculators.htm by setting 3 and 1000 then press calculate.

Comment: @rasul_rza24 let me know if you are still in doubt

Comment: So it seems the answer is $3\sigma$, right?

Comment: in one side, you say answer should be lying between $4\sigma$ and $5\sigma$, but on the other hand you mention $3\sigma$ as an answer. So, what is exactly answer to this problem?

Comment: If we talk about sigma level it is between 4 and 5. if we talk about normal sigma it is between 2.8 and 3. Final answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, answer is absolutely right!

Comment: @rasul_rza24 haha thank you for the feedback makes me happy to know it was helpful!

Comment: I posted a new problem (about graphs), could you please look up? I am sure your contribution and research would be immense to solve that problem